# PHP ¿Se puede pasar una función como parámetro de otra?

Tags: php

Lo que quería hacer es indicarle a una función que función debería usar para realizar una tarea.

```
function principal ($parametro1, $parametro2, ..., $funcion)
{
  [...]
  $b = $funcion($variable);
  [...]
}
```

Así dependiendo de la función que le pase, conseguiría que la variable `$b` tuviera un valor u otro según las necesidades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que intentas hacer se conoce como una ***funcion anonima*.**

Estas son funciones que **no tienen un nombre especifico** y como tal las puedes pasar como si fueran un **argumento** en una funcion.

He aqui un ejemplo:

```
<?php

/** 
  Creamos la funcion anonima, 
  que podra ser accedida 
  a traves de la variable $funcion
*/
$funcion = function($parametro){
    print "Parametro: $parametro\n";
};

/** 
   Creamos la funcion principal() 
   y en ella recibimos como parametros 
   un valor y una funcion anonima
*/
function principal($argumento, $funcion){

    print "Argumento: $argumento\n";
    $funcion(10);

}

/** 
   Llamamos a las funcion principal() 
*/
principal(15, $funcion);


?>
```

> Resultado

```
Argumento: 15
Parametro: 10
```

[**Ver en linea!**](https://tio.run/##bY/LasMwEEX3@ooheGGbQJpFN03TELLtoh/QzUSeNgK9OrYDpeTb3ZGpbEOzkzRnru6JlzgMz4d4iUpt6hoUwIkJXWjBInz0XpvgAX3wxuE6jb96ghgaRmiJAbWmxjSYJggd45VaaCgtX5ENni1B8Rej6o3KZ9iP4Z0cyyIio6OOQ/UjMQCRje9g9Zafn2BG3v1qp267qe29umlfm4i2rEbkG8gDWSGYtDmbhOvgAkyp7cj1XkrbwLLQ@3/2qX7uvPiiQP7sHfkurCdT8ViKHDMhIhM9iiQoL5Xbh0q8brPaq0U3uqHYtff1pNR83z4uOkiWOrwMwy8)

#### Actualizacion

A continuacion agrego un ejemplo, para que nos quede mas claro, esto acerca de las funciones anonimas:

```
<?php


$suma = function($a, $b){
    return $a + $b;
};

$resta = function($a, $b){
    return $a + $b;
};

function calcular($operacion, $a, $b){

   global $suma, $resta;

   $resultado = NULL;

    switch($operacion){

        case 'SUMA':
            $resultado = $suma($a, $b);

        case 'RESTA':
            $resultado = $resta($a,$b);

    }

   return $resultado;
}

$resultado = calcular('SUMA', 10, 15);

print "Resultado:" . $resultado . "\n";

?>
```

> Resultado

```
Resultado:25
```

Siempre puedes encontrar mas informacion en la [documentacion de PHP.](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias, sabía que se podía hacer, pero como un desastre con los nombres no me acordaba y no era capaz a encontrar la información. Y los ejemplos están muy bien.

Answer (score 1):

Sí se puede. Hay varias funciones en PHP que esperan un ejecutable como parámetro. Por ejemplo en el caso de array_filter, para filtrar los números pares de un array:

```
<?php
 function espar($numero) {
   return (($numero % 2) == 0);
 }

 $arreglo =[1,2,3,4,5,6];

 $pares = array_filter($arreglo, 'espar');
```

En ese caso, `espar` se pone como string porque es un callable declarado en el ámbito global.

Acorde a tu ejemplo, esto se puede hacer como:

```
<?php
 $espar = function($numero) {
   return (($numero % 2) == 0);
 };

 $arreglo =[1,2,3,4,5,6];

 $pares = array_filter($arreglo, $espar);
```

Y por supuesto también puede hacerce como una función anónima que nace y muere en el llamado:

```
<?php
 $arreglo =[1,2,3,4,5,6];

 $pares = array_filter($arreglo, function($numero) {
    return $numero%2 == 0;
 });
```

Para las funciones que tú mismo construyas, puedes aplicarlas exactamente como mostraste en tu pregunta. El argumento que espera una función también puede recibir un método de clase, en particular puede recibir métodos estáticos de una clase que contenga tus funciones, para evitarte llenar el espacio global con funciones.